# How to extract specific elements conditionally?

Tags: r, list

I have a following list:

```
name <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
n1 <- c(NA, "foo", "hoo", "haa", "hee")
n2 <- c("foo", "hoo", NA, "haa", "hee")
n3 <- c("foo", NA, "hoo", "haa", "hee")
    
list <- list(name=name, n1=n1, n2=n2, n3=n3)

$name
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

$n1
[1] NA    "foo" "hoo" "haa" "hee"

$n2
[1] "foo" "hoo" NA    "haa" "hee"

$n3
[1] "foo" NA    "hoo" "haa" "hee"
```

Each element of the list has the same number of vectors (`5`).
I need to extract elements which fulfill the requirement, i.e., `n1!=NA`, `n2!=NA` or `n3!=NA`.

If I adapt the condition `n1!=NA`, the following list will be generated.

```
$name
[1] "B" "C" "D" "E"

$n1
[1] "foo" "hoo" "haa" "hee"

$n2
[1] "hoo" NA    "haa" "hee"

$n3
[1] NA    "hoo" "haa" "hee"
```

This is another example of `n2!=NA`:

```
$name
[1] "A" "B" "D" "E"

$n1
[1] NA "foo" "haa" "hee"

$n2
[1] "foo" "hoo" "haa" "hee"
```

And this is the last example of `n3!=NA`:

```
$name
[1] "A" "C" "D" "E"

$n1
[1] NA "hoo" "haa" "hee"

$n2
[1] "foo" NA    "haa" "hee"

$n3
[1] "foo" "hoo" "haa" "hee"
```

Actually I am not familiar with manipulating `list` in `R` as I used to work with `data frame`. It is easy to implement it in `data.frame` by running `df %>% filter(n1!=NA)` using `dplyr`, however, in the list format, I cannot simply implement this as each element is not corresponded.

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, `!is.na(...)` not, `... != NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index on non-NAs for each element, i.e.

```
lapply(list1, `[`, which(!is.na(list1$n1)))
$name
[1] "B" "C" "D" "E"

$n1
[1] "foo" "hoo" "haa" "hee"

$n2
[1] "hoo" NA    "haa" "hee"

$n3
[1] NA    "hoo" "haa" "hee"

> lapply(list1, `[`, which(!is.na(list1$n2)))
$name
[1] "A" "B" "D" "E"

$n1
[1] NA    "foo" "haa" "hee"

$n2
[1] "foo" "hoo" "haa" "hee"

$n3
[1] "foo" NA    "haa" "hee"

> lapply(list1, `[`, which(!is.na(list1$n3)))
$name
[1] "A" "C" "D" "E"

$n1
[1] NA    "hoo" "haa" "hee"

$n2
[1] "foo" NA    "haa" "hee"

$n3
[1] "foo" "hoo" "haa" "hee"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, changing `list` to dataframe would help with manipulation.

```
tmp <- as.data.frame(list)

subset_data <- function(data, col) {
  as.list(data[!is.na(data[[col]]), ])
}

subset_data(tmp, 'n1')

#$name
#[1] "B" "C" "D" "E"

#$n1
#[1] "foo" "hoo" "haa" "hee"

#$n2
#[1] "hoo" NA    "haa" "hee"

#$n3
#[1] NA    "hoo" "haa" "hee"
```